# How to define start and end times in python

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7, time, scheduling

I am using the code

```
def run_periodically(start, end, interval, func):
    event_time = start
    while event_time < end:
        s.enterabs(event_time, 0, func, ())
        event_time += interval + random(-5, 45)
    s.run()

    run_periodically(time()+5, time()+1000000, 10, getData)
```

Now If I wanted to define the start time as 22.00 how is this formatted in python?

e.g. I would change the code to

```
starttime = #?#

run_periodically(starttime(), time()+1000000, 10, getData)
```

What is the standard time formatting used to make this work?

Comment: your code and wording is confusing. Could you put a more detailed explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python time() related functions take the number of seconds since a particular date (depending on your os). You can convert that from the `datetime` types using  `datetime.time()`

```
import datetime
timestamp = datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 6, 18, 1).time()
```

That makes `timestamp` usable for `run_periodically`.

You can also go the other way by using `datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())`.
All this and more detailed info can be found in the [module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

Comment: Does this `timestamp = datetime(2013, 6, 4, 6, 18, 1).time()` set the time to be 6:18:01 on the 4th of the 6th month? ?

Comment: Yes, international like ordering: year, month, day, hour, minute, second. I used todays date (and about the current time at that moment). Also inserted an extra .datetime as the objects and the module have the same name